# The operators "Is one of etc" not working with exposed filters

Tags: views

The `"Is one of etc"` operators do not seem to reduce the result set on **exposed** filters. So for example if I have all fruits and select only mango and apple with "is one of" - The result set only shows mangoes and apples if I do not expose the fruit filter. But if I expose the fruit filter, it shows all the fruits.  My view is based on a search index configured with search API.

Is this expected behaviour or am I missing something?

Comment: Check the default display option in that filter.

Answer (score 1):

Expose the filter, then select the fruits that you need to show and then enable the "Limit list to selected items" option, so the dropdown list filter will only show the fruits that you want, not all of them.